# validate field if another field is set in django form

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am quite lost with django form validiation, although I read the docs.

I have defined the following form:

```
class NewProjAccount(NewAccount):
    def __init__(self, perforce='', *args, **kwargs):
        super(NewProjAccount, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        print perforce
        if 'on' in perforce:
            self.fields['perforce_depot_size'].widget.attrs[
                'required'] = True

    site = forms.ChoiceField(choices=SITE_CHOICES, required=False,
                             label="Site")
    project_name = forms.CharField(max_length=25, required=True,)
    disk_usage = forms.IntegerField(max_value=PROJ_MAX_SIZE_GB,
                                    )
    homes = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=SITE_CHOICES, required=False,
                                      widget=
                                      forms.widgets.CheckboxSelectMultiple(),
                                      label="Remote Homes")
    perforce_depot = forms.BooleanField(required=False)
    perforce_depot_size = forms.IntegerField(max_value=PERFORCE_MAX_SIZE_GB,
                                             required=False)

class ReviewProjAccount(NewProjAccount):
    site = forms.CharField(max_length=20, required=False,
                           label="Site")
    project_name = forms.CharField(max_length=25, required=True,)
    homes = forms.CharField(label="Remote Homes")
    perforce_depot = forms.BooleanField(required=False,
                                       widget=forms.widgets.CheckboxInput(
                                       attrs={'disabled': 'disabled'}))
```

Both forms inherit from:

```
class NewAccount(forms.Form):
    """
    Base class for all the account type
    """
    def __init__(self, readonly=False, *args, **kwargs):
        super(NewAccount, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        if readonly:
            for field in self.fields.itervalues():
                field.widget.attrs['readonly'] = 'readonly'
```

My idea was to use that form like this:

```
 if request.method == 'POST':           
    try:
        form = NewProjAccount(perforce=request.POST['perforce_depot'],
                              data=request.POST)
    except MultiValueDictKeyError:
        print "caugh"
        if request.POST['perforce_depot_size']:
            form = ReviewProjAccount(data=initial_val,
                                 readonly=True)
        else:
            form = NewProjAccount(data=request.POST)
```

However, this results in a very complicated view function with may 'if' and 'else' and
'try  ... example' ...

#### So, my question is:

Is there a simple way to define a relationship between to field in forms, such that when 
one is `True`, it triggers a validator for another filed?
In my case, I would like to when the user choose:
`perforce_depot = True`, or `'on'` the `perforce_depot_size` should have the attribute `required` set to `True`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can take a look at [Cleaning and validating fields that depend on each other](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other)

```
from django import forms

class NewProjAccount(forms.Form):
    #form attributes

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(NewProjAccount, self).clean()
        perforce_depot = cleaned_data.get("perforce_depot")
        perforce_depot_size = cleaned_data.get("perforce_depot_size")

        if perforce_depot and not perforce_depot_size:
            raise forms.ValidationError("perforce_depot_size needs to be set to true.")

        # Always return the full collection of cleaned data.
        return cleaned_data
```

Also, i would recommend taking a look at django's [ModelForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform), which would reduce your code tremendously, and would keep it much simpler

Comment: it seems your solution works, but I don't know why I don't see the error of that field `perforce_depot_size` in the template. Any ideas?

Comment: Yeah. You are not raising the validation on the specific field. Hence the error

Comment: What I mean is `{{ form.non_field_errors }}` works, but how can I make this error to a field error?

Comment: It is in the next part of the [link that i shared](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other)